# What is the thing under the power/sleep button on an iPhone 12 Pro Max?

Tags: iphone

There's a thing on the right side of the iPhone 12 Pro Max (and I'm guessing all modern iPhones) below the power button.

[image: Photo of right edge of iPhone]

In the photo, the green arrow points to the power button, and the red arrow points to the thing I'm asking about.

It looks like the same kind of material used on TV remotes to cover the IR emitter.  Does the iPhone have such an emitter?  If this *is* an IR emitter, can we use it somehow?

This has probably been asked before, but since I don't know how to describe the thing I'm asking about, I don't even know how to search for an answer.  I googled *iPhone 12 Pro Max diagram*, but none of them labeled this piece.  When I googled *iPhone IR* I found such titles as "Why doesn't the iPhone have an IR blaster?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the mmWave antenna on a US iPhone.

https://www.patentlyapple.com/2021/06/apple-describes-the-use-of-multiple-millimeter-wave-antennas-in-future-iphones-that-will-provide-superior-5g-communications.html